# SqlDataAdapter Fill Error

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

I have two table , User and UserReputation . I want to get data with SqlDataAdapter.

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abc.com;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter userDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM User", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter userReputationDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UserReputation", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        userDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "User");
        userReputationDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "UserReputation");
```

I tested the connection string and connection.There is no problem.But I got below error at the `userDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "User");`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM [User]"
```

`User` is a keyword, if you have `Table` named "User" you should use brackets
or as @Rahul has mentioned you can also use `""`:

```
"SELECT * FROM \"User\""
```

Comment: You can as well use `""` for escaping since that's ANSI standard

Comment: @Rahul I have added that to the answer as it can be useful for somebody searching for this problem